# Implementing multiple builds with AWS codebuild, with dependant artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration

I currently work on a project that makes use of AWS CodeBuild for our CI workflow. There is currently one big build, that takes up quite a bit of time as it includes an e2e test suite that takes some time to run, and can sometimes be flaky, causing the whole build to fail and need to be restarted.

I would like it if we could split our build down into smaller, modular builds, that could run independently (and also provide independent status feedback to the associated PR on GitHub).

I was looking at using CodePipeline to achieve this, however it would seem CodePipeline is only configurable to run against master (or a specified branch), rather than on a per PR basis. We would like our tests to run against PRs and prevent erroneous code from being merged into master in the first place.

I was thinking, would it be possible just to use codebuild to achieve this, with multiple builders responsible for different build tasks (for example linting/unit testing could happen in one builder, separate to compiling the application, and running the e2e tests).

I would love something like:

```
 |----------|     |---------|
 | Compiler |     | Linter  |
 | Builder  |     | Builder | 
 |----------|     |---------|
      |      \
      |       \
|-----------|  |----------|
| Unit Test |  | E2E Test |
| Builder   |  | Builder  |
|-----------|  |----------|
```

Where each box represents a CodeBuild builder/buildspec and the line represents an artefact dependency.

Here, the 'Compiler Builder' and 'Linter Builder' are kicked off on push to the PR. When the 'Compiler Builder' completes, it transfers the build artefacts of the compiled code to the 'Unit Test Builder', and the 'e2e Builder' for each of these test suites to run, which both report back independent status's to the PR.

It seems like CodePipeline is the ideal tool for this sort of thing, only it does not work using a compatible workflow for our team.

It isn't clear to me how to go about setting something like this up for CodeBuild, though I have seen people allude to it on other posts/SO questions that you can use other AWS services to orchestrate this sort of thing (AWS Lambda/AWS Step Functions). I am not particularly clued up on AWS services, and what is and isn't possible which is why I am asking here. I just want confirmation that what I describe above *is* possible, and which services will need to be used to achieve this.

I think one of the key hurdles I am struggling with is how to make the output from one codebuild build become the input for another, I have looked at using S3 for storing build artifacts, though I'm not sure how to use that in another build, which is also then connected to GitHub, and able to report a status back to a PR.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I have the same requirement, wanting to have several builds that depend on each other. I tried doing this using the Batch build [build-graph](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/batch-build-buildspec.html#build-spec.batch.build-graph) feature of CodeBuild  and it kinda works, I'm just not able to export variables for the following deployment actions.

Answer (score 0):

In CodePipeline, each action (within each stage) has an input artifact and output artifact.
This can be use to solve your specific hurdle.

As you described, some jobs (actions) should run in parallel (i.e. on same stage) and should output their artifacts to the output-artifact.

Other jobs should run in serial, so they should occur on another stage (e.g. afterwards) and those jobs (actions) may make use of the previous output artifacts as their input-artifact.

[image: AWS CodePipeline Edit Action]